# How to do some action after retrieving data using async pipe in angular 10

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

I am using **async pipe** to bind data as below: (Angular 10)

app.component.html:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngFor="let customer of customers | async">
        <tr>
            <td>{{customer.id}}</td>
            <td>{{customer.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

app.component.ts:

```
constructor(private customersService: CustomersService) { }
    customers:Observable<any>;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.customers = this.customersService.getCustomers();
      }
```

> Here I am calling getCustomers() method, which fetch data from api via
> http GET method and assigning to customers observable.

It works correctly. I want to do some action after retrieving data from api.

So how to achieve this using async pipe ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could pipe in a [`tap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap) operator to the source to perform some side-effects.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.customers = this.customersService.getCustomers().pipe(
    tap(res => {
      // do something with `res`
    })
  );
}
```

The actions inside the `tap` will be performed for each notification from the observable and does not affect the source notification.

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zxsflv?file=src/app/customers.service.ts)

Comment: what is the exact purpose of tap operator? can I use map?

Comment: `map` is similar to `tap` except it is used to return a transformed value. Think of `tap` as `map` without the return. So any operations inside `tap` doesn't have any bearing on the emitted value. `map` is usually use to transform the emitted value. For eg. you receive some object and you wish to extract and use only one value out of it.

Comment: @chirag: I've added a working example to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

[**`Async`**](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) acts like subscription and prevents the memory leaks. To perform any action we can use map or filter to manipulate the data.

You can do something like below,

```
 ngOnInit() {
     this.customers = this.customersService.getCustomers().map(resp => {
          // do the actions you want
     });
 }
```

Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: I think is map is old syntax, its not working in angular 10

Comment: No it's not, it works perfectly in my angular 10 app =) Though you may include the map into a pipe as stated by Michael D this.customers = this.customersService.getCustomers().pipe(map(res => {
             return {sumthing: res.id}; // this is an example
    })
  );